# Pick up successive lines containing keywords in order

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a tab-separated file that looks as follows:

```
$ cat file
GCF_000015405.1_ASM1540v1.dist_nbr_anntn        WP_011558474.1  1159543 1160595 -4330977        polyketide synthase [Mycobacterium]
GCF_000015405.1_ASM1540v1.dist_nbr_anntn        WP_011558475.1  1160607 1161116 12      isoprenylcysteine carboxyl methyltransferase [Mycobacterium]
GCF_000015405.1_ASM1540v1.dist_nbr_anntn        WP_011558476.1  1161113 1162129 -3      NAD(P)/FAD-dependent oxidoreductase [Mycobacterium]
GCF_000015405.1_ASM1540v1.dist_nbr_anntn        WP_011559726.1  2496640 2497560 1334511 polyketide synthase [Mycobacterium]
GCF_000015405.1_ASM1540v1.dist_nbr_anntn        WP_011559727.1  2497568 2498122 8       isoprenylcysteine carboxyl methyltransferase [Mycobacterium]
GCF_000015405.1_ASM1540v1.dist_nbr_anntn        WP_011562574.1  5526997 5528142 3028875 NAD(P)/FAD-dependent oxidoreductase [Mycobacterium]
```

I need to pick up *successive lines* that contain the keywords 'polyketide synthase', 'methyltransferase', and 'oxidoreductase' *in that order*, and write each of these sets into separate files for further analysis.

In this case, the input file would yield 2 output files which would look as follows:

```
$ cat file_1
GCF_000015405.1_ASM1540v1.dist_nbr_anntn        WP_011558474.1  1159543 1160595 -4330977        polyketide synthase [Mycobacterium]
GCF_000015405.1_ASM1540v1.dist_nbr_anntn        WP_011558475.1  1160607 1161116 12      isoprenylcysteine carboxyl methyltransferase [Mycobacterium]
GCF_000015405.1_ASM1540v1.dist_nbr_anntn        WP_011558476.1  1161113 1162129 -3      NAD(P)/FAD-dependent oxidoreductase [Mycobacterium]

$ cat file_2
GCF_000015405.1_ASM1540v1.dist_nbr_anntn        WP_011559726.1  2496640 2497560 1334511 polyketide synthase [Mycobacterium]
GCF_000015405.1_ASM1540v1.dist_nbr_anntn        WP_011559727.1  2497568 2498122 8       isoprenylcysteine carboxyl methyltransferase [Mycobacterium]
GCF_000015405.1_ASM1540v1.dist_nbr_anntn        WP_011562574.1  5526997 5528142 3028875 NAD(P)/FAD-dependent oxidoreductase [Mycobacterium]
```

I am having a hard time doing this using awk. Any suggestions?

**P.S.** I have other input files that contain variable number of instances of the keywords in successive lines. This is where I am getting stuck.

Comment: What make those two output files `file_1` & `file_2` different fro each other? what other files you are talking about `other files that contain variable number of instances of the keywords in successive lines`? please [edit] your question and make it a little more clear.

Comment: @αғsнιη Sorry if I was unclear in my question. file_1 and file_2 would contain different sets of the keyword instances in successive lines (you could look at the intended output files in the question for further clarification).
Also, I have made the requested edit in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change what you are searching for as the script progresses and change where you write to each time you cycle through your terms

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    result_file = 1;
    term_id = 1;
    search_terms[1] = "polyketide synthase";
    search_terms[2] = "methyltransferase";
    search_terms[3] = "oxidoreductase"
}
$0 ~ search_terms[term_id] { 
    print $0 >> FILENAME "_" result_file;
    term_id = term_id + 1;
    if (term_id > 3) {
        result_file =  result_file + 1;
        term_id = 1
    }
}' input_file
```

This will write to `input_file_1`, `input_file_2`...

Answer (score 1):

You might test the following code, where I split your keywords into an `awk` array named  `keys` with `N` elements. everything starts with keys[1] and we set up a flag to check the next 1 to `N-1` lines if they matches the corresponding values in the array keys [index from 2 to N], any mismatches before the N-1 line will reset this flag, if it reaches the `N-1` line, then all are good for output (we also reset flag=0 here so a consecutive run of flag==1 never exceeds `N-1` lines):

```
$ cat t24.awk
BEGIN{ 
    FS = OFS = "\t";
    keywords = "polyketide synthase,methyltransferase,oxidoreductase";
    N = split(keywords, keys, ",")
}

# flag==1 means we are doing regex_match the next N-1 lines
# against corresponding array element in keys from [2:N] 
# once a unmatched found, turn off flag immediately
# if the flag==1 reached N-1 lines, then print the good match
flag {
    if($NF ~ keys[NR - start_line + 1]) {
        F = F ORS $0;
        if (NR == start_line+N-1) {print F > "out_" f++; flag = 0 }
        next
    } else {
        flag = 0;
    }
}

# set up the flag/start_line and reset F
$NF ~ keys[1] { flag = 1; F = $0; start_line= NR; }
```

Run the above code with `awk -f t24.awk file.txt`. You can set up `keywords` (comma delimited) from your shell(instead of hard-coded in the `BEGIN` block), and then use `-v keywords="..."` to make it more flexible.